# What type of connection is required for the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet Theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

How general a connection on $TM$ can be used in the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem?  Wikipedia only states the theorem for the Levi-Civita connection, but this is probably needlessly restrictive.  (If the theorem can be proven for the LC connection of *some* metric then it holds for the LC connection for *any* metric, and so we see already that there is some family of connections for which it holds. 
 This is also asserted in Q. Yuan's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843435/can-we-define-flat-connection-on-any-given-smooth-manifold?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

What I understand of Chern-Weil theory suggests that the theorem should hold for any connection whatsoever on $TM$, but perhaps I am missing something.  Chern seems to only consider Levi-Civita connections in *A Simple Intrinsic Proof of the Gauss-Bonnet Formula for Closed Riemannian Manifolds*.

Comment: Incidentally, it is a famous open problem due to Chern : Does the existence of a flat affine connection on a compact manifold imply zero Euler characteristic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by generalized Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem we mean that $\chi(M)=\frac1{(2\pi)^n}\int_M\textrm{Pf}(\Omega)$, where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic, $\Omega$ is the curvature form, and Pf is the Pfaffian, then it is false for general connections. Beneventano et al. show in [Heat trace asymptotics and the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem for general connections](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6301) that when the connection is not Levi-Civita the correct integrand is not the Pfaffian. One can write a formula that works in general using the $L_2$ trace of the heat semigroup, but it is not nearly as useful.

Zhao proved a positive result in [A note on the Gauss-Bonnet-Chern theorem for general connection](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3171). The connection need not be the Levi-Civita, but it has to be metric compatible. This means, in particular, that  $\nabla g=0$ for some $g$, i.e. its restricted holonomy group is conjugated to a subgroup of $O(n)$, but it is not necessarily torsion-free, see [Does the Levi-Civita connection determine the metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1198063/152568)

Comment: Thank you for these helpful references.  If I understood Beneventano et al, the local densities that we integrate to compute the heat trace are no longer only functions of the connection's curvature -- is that correct?  And so this is why merely finding a flat affine connection is not enough to conclude that $\chi(M)=0$, whereas a flat _metric_ connection does imply zero Euler characteristic?

Comment: @ToddN Yes, they identified some asymptotic terms that do not come from curvature but contribute to the sum. But now that I thought about Zhao's result some more, I think what he means by "metric compatible" is that the connection does differentiate the metric to $0$, but is not necessarily torsion-free.